# Setting cookie and retrieving cookie inside phonegap app for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova

I am developing an app with phonegap for windows phone 8.
I want to detect if cookie is enabled in user's browser.

I am using the below code for testing cookies

```
var name="test1";
var value="teshghghg";
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) ;
alert(document.cookie.length);
```

When i check the cookiecentral.com or w3schools.com,i can see that cookie's are getting set in mobile IE 10 browser.

The above code prints 0 length inside phone gap app.
Any leads are greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance